# Why does this equation hold?

Tags: number-theory, modular-forms

Let $K(\sqrt{D})$ be a real quadratic field with discriminant D and $a$ an integral ideal with its norm $N(a)$ .

I do not know why the following equation holds using the theta transformation formula $$\sum_{\lambda\equiv0(a)}e^{-\pi t(\lambda^2e^v+\overline \lambda^2e^{-v})}=\frac{1}{t\sqrt{D}N(a)}\sum_{v\equiv0 \frac{1}{a\sqrt{D}}} e^{\frac{-\pi v^2e^{-v}+\overline v^2e^v}{t}}$$

Comment: What is $\lambda$ and $v$ .. You are supposed to find $M\in GL_2(\Bbb{R})$ such that it is  $$= \sum_{n \in Z^2} e^{-\pi t \|M n\|^2}= t^{-1/2} \det(M)^{-1} \sum_{k \in Z^2} e^{-\pi t \|M^{-\top} n\|^2}$$ either you'll define $M$ explicitly and compute its inverse, or you'll define $\|M n\|^2$ in term of the field traces on the lattice $L\subset \Bbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$ you are summing over and show $M^{-\top}$ is the norm on the [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Different_ideal) of $L$. Those things are proven eg. in Neukrich book.

Comment: Thanks for your answer . $v \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in a$ .